# How to instantiate ref after passing to prop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The code below pass jsx from parent to child;
The problem is that the reference `row.descBox` is undefined, maybe due to jsx in `parent.js` is not yet run;
how should I make it point to the `span` element?

This is Parent.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
  const taskRefs = useRef([]);
  const [cellContent, setCellContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cellContent = [
      {
        content: (
          <>
            <h1>
              <span
                ref={(el) => {
                  taskRefs.current[0] = el;
                }}
              >
                inside span
              </span>
            </h1>
          </>
        ),
        descBox: taskRefs.current[0]
      }
    ];

    setCellContent(cellContent);
  }, []);

  return <Child cellContent={cellContent} />;
}
```

This is Child.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export const Child = ({ cellContent }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cellContent.map((row, i) => {
        {
          console.log(row.descBox);//this is null!
          return <div key={i}>{row.content}</div>;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Try the code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-booth-pwp62x?file=/src/Parent.js:0-698)

Comment: You're logging before the element has been rendered so the ref isn't set yet. If you log the ref in a `useEffect` in `Child` you'll see it set. (but you can't set `descBox` to `taskRefs.current[0]` as it will then be locked as `undefined`. You need to assign it either the ref `taskRefs` or the `taskRefs.current` as both of these will be updated by reference when the ref is finally set) [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-buxnpi?file=/src/Child.js)

Comment: Holding a ref to an unmounted element is meaningless in the React life cycle, and storing jsx in a property is not the same as storing an actual DOM element. Even if you were able to 'instantiate a ref' before mount, mounting the the stored jsx would create a *new* element and you would lose referential equality. This is striking me as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is your actual goal? There is bound to be a standard pattern that fulfills it.

Comment: @pilchard it works thanks, the use case is passing elements to component like a table. Also I have change the "before" to "after" in the title, what you said make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback to set the ref inside the stored jsx won't be run until the component is mounted in the DOM and logging inside the `map()` is before that happens (you haven't even returned it yet). You'll need to log in a `useEffect` in order to see it set. I've added `log` calls to each step in the snippet below to illustrate the order.

As a side note, can't set `descBox` to `taskRefs.current[0]` as it will then be locked as `undefined`. You will need to assign it either the ref object `taskRefs` or the nested array assigned to `taskRefs.current` as either of these will be updated by reference when the ref is finally set).

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const taskRefs = useRef([]);
  const [cellContent, setCellContent] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cellContent = [
      {
        content: (
          <span
            ref={(el) => {
              console.log("setting ref");
              taskRefs.current[0] = el;
            }}
          >
            inside span
          </span>
        ),
        descBox: taskRefs
      }
    ];

    setCellContent(cellContent);
  }, []);

  return <Child cellContent={cellContent} />;
}

function Child({ cellContent }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cellContent.length) {
      console.log("inside useEffect. Ref:",cellContent[0].descBox.current[0]);
    } else {
      console.log('first render.');
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cellContent.map((row, i) => {
        console.log("inside map. Ref:", row.descBox.current[0]);
        return <div key={i}>{row.content}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-buxnpi?file=/src/Child.js)